# Partial quantile moments?

Tags: terminology, quantiles, moments, partial-moments

The integral from 0 to x* of x to the n times pdf(x) is usually called the *nth partial moment function*. Does the corresponding integral from 0 to y* of y to the n of the quantile density function, qdf(y), have a name by which it is most commonly referred in the literature?

Comment: Since even "qdf" is a rather rare term in statistics (although the concept is well known), it might be fruitless to seek a "commonly referred" name.  Is there instead a specific statistical problem you are trying to solve that we could help with?